# Elixir function behaves differently in iex and from command line

Tags: elixir

I have a very simple Elixir project which contains a function `primes_table`. Here's the first bit of it...

```
  def primes_table(n) do
    header_row(n) <> rows(n)
  end

  def header_row(n) do
    "|" <> pad("", n) <> header_row_columns(n) <> "\n"
  end
```

When called in iex:

```
iex(1)> Primestable.primes_table(3)
"|    |  2 |  3 |  5 |\n|  2 |  4 |  6 | 10 |\n|  3 |  6 |  9 | 15 |\n|  5 | 10 | 15 | 25 |"
```

When called from the command line:

```
$ ./primestable 3
|     |
```

So it's getting as far as outputting `"|" <> pad("", n)` but no further. Without wishing to horrify you all with too much newbie Elixir code, can anyone think of a good explanation for why I would be getting a very different result from my escript? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the correct argument (3 in this case) is passed to the function `primes_table`?

Comment: @helios35 99.5% sure. `main` passes the args to a `process(n)` function, whose body is `IO.puts primes_table(n)`. If I replace that with `IO.puts n`, I see 3 as the output.

Comment: And the type is also correct? (check with `is_integer`, for example).

Comment: Ooh, now that sounds like something that I might have overlooked. Thank you!

Comment: Just a general advice, avoid using `IO.puts` for debugging purposes since you cannot distinguish strings from integers as well as strings from charlists. Use `IO.inspect` instead.

Comment: IO.inspect, great tip. Thanks again.